# Spring Boot : Apache CXF SOAP with @RestController for rest ws

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, cxf

I'm working SOAP and REST together into the same application. Rest web service with @RestController and SOAP with apache cxf.
Rest ws and soap have the same path, for example:
Rest: GET http://localhost:8080/ws/person
SOAP: http://localhost:8080/ws/findPerson

For configuring cxf servlet, i create the following method

```
@Bean 
public ServletRegistrationBean cxfServletRegistration() {
                return new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), "/ws/*");  }
```

SOAP Service are running fine after change but REST (@RestController) stop working, but if I disable the method cxfServletRegistration(), the rest WS working fine.

Could you suggest any solution to make all WS working together ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, because each servlet must "own" its listening basepath.  Despite the lack of an explicit registration, RestControllers listen on a base path (default /*)  Do you actually need to use @RestController?  CXF has REST support via JAX-RS.

Otherwise, I would suggest to separate your REST and SOAP functionality, such as having REST on /model/... and SOAP on /api/... or some such separation.